# How can I fix error toedit pages based on id?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I get error when i click on edit button it show error in img src(null reference)

***This is EDit functionality of Member Controller***

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int memberId)
        {
            var memeber = await _context.Member.FindAsync(memberId); // Getting member by Id from database
            return View(new MemberViewModel() { Member = memeber });

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(MemberViewModel model, IFormFile photo/*int id, [Bind("MemberId,Name,Gender,DOB,MaritalStatus,Address,PhoneNo,Skills,Hobbies,JobTitle,Technology")] Member member*/)
        {
            if (photo == null || photo.Length == 0)
            {
                return Content("File not selected");
            }
   
            var path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnviroment.WebRootPath, "ImageName/Cover", photo.FileName);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }
            model.Member.ImageName = photo.FileName;

            //Finding the member by its Id which we would update
            var objMember = _context.Member.Where(mId => mId.MemberId == model.Member.MemberId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (objMember != null)
            {
                //Update the existing member with new value
                objMember!.Name = model.Member.Name;
                objMember!.Gender = model.Member.Gender;
                objMember!.DOB = model.Member.DOB;
                objMember!.MaritalStatus = model.Member.MaritalStatus;
                objMember!.Address = model.Member.Address;
                objMember!.PhoneNo = model.Member.PhoneNo;
                objMember!.Skills = model.Member.Skills;
                objMember!.Hobbies = model.Member.Hobbies;
                objMember!.JobTitle = model.Member.JobTitle;
                objMember!.Technology = model.Member.Technology;
                objMember!.ImageName = model.Member.ImageName;
                objMember!.ImageLocation = path;

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

***And this is a View Where I get Error***

```
@model TeamManagement.ViewModel.MemberViewModel

<form asp-action="Edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">MemberPicture</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <img src="~/ImageName/Cover/@Model.Member.ImageName"
                     class="rounded-square"
                     height="50" width="75"
                     style="border:1px"
                     asp-append-version="true" accept="image/*" />
                <span><a href="@Model.Member.ImageName">@Model.Member.ImageName</a></span>
                <div id="chooseFile">
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***This is my ViewModel name as MemberVieModel***

```
using System;
using TeamManagement.Models;

namespace TeamManagement.ViewModel
{
    public class MemberViewModel
    {
        public Member Member { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View Model ScreenShot

[image]

So that is I tried your Code that will running when i implement on my code they give that error

Comment: Did you pt the debug pointer where exactly throwing the error?

Comment: Let me investigate that at my end.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your file structure `TeamManagement.ViewModel.MemberViewModel`?

Comment: @Gourav problem is there `TeamManagement.ViewModel.MemberViewModel`

Comment: Where is your `<form asp-action="EditMember" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` In edit view page?

Comment: see i update in question `<form asp-action="EditMember" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Okay got your update

Comment: Are you still struggling with the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get error when I click on edit button it show error in img src (null reference)

This is because you haven't followed the instruction accordingly. You haven't set `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.MemberId" />` at the beginning on your `form` so the compiler doesn't get Id which `Id` need to be update. So set the `Member.MemberId` on the top of your `form` as hidden item it's mandatory for 'edit':

Error you will encounter at:

```
  var objMember = _context.Member.Where(mId => mId.MemberId == model.Member.MemberId).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Note:** When you will not set `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.MemberId" />` at your `form` here it will not get the reference which Id need to be update and throw the error you are getting.

**Solution:**

```
<form asp-action="EditMember" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.MemberId" />
 </form>
```

**Another point:**

Make sure you have set the `[Key]` on the top of your `Member` Model. It should be like below:

```
public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

        public string? ImageName { get; set; }
        public string? ImageLocation { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Comment: what are changes

Comment: See the updated answer here and try it.

Comment: i use both of this `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.MemberId" />`

Comment: See the code which you have shared earlier. Its doesn't containing that

Comment: yes i don't select these two lines i only select form element  Sorry